# how to remove part of matched string in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I would like to delete part of the string that is matched with a regular expression.
My approach is to find a match, then `str.replace()` it with a blank `''`. However, for the following text, I am having trouble isolating the string. I tried isolating the part that I do not want to replace, and select the oppostie of it to replace:

Text: 
`2/3.00`

regular expression used: `/([^\/]*)$/g`

output: `3.00`

expected output `2/`

Basically I want to replace everything up to and including the first `/` with a `''`.

Comment: please add the wanted result. is it `2`?

Comment: Please show the code that does the actual matching/replacing.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```js
let str = '2/3.00'

console.log(str.replace(/.+\//, ''))
```

Comment: This seems to be working.. I will test it out. My idea was `.[\/]` but I realised this only matches the slash and the character right before it.

Comment: this will also remove the slash

Comment: @slartidan As was requested: "replace everything up to and including the first /"

Comment: @Schlaus: But your regex matches everything up to and including the *last* `/`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True. With just one, very short sample to go by I could be way off in a number of ways. If it's not sufficient for the op, I'll try to come up with a better solution.